# Horizontal Step Carousel

Tags: scrollbar, scroll

Step Carousel
http://www.harrods.com/harrodsstore/

I need a flash or jquery Horizontal Step Carousel which has auto scroll feature and scrollbar at the bottom. Anyone saw it something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one: http://plugins.jquery.com/node/11222/release